# didSelectItemAt indexPath not fully called until second click

Tags: xcode, collectionview

So it seems like some things in the code for "didselectitem" gets called on the first selection of a cell, but others don't update until the second click.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let cellSize = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.frame.size

    popup.frame.size = cellSize!


    popupWordLabel.text = itemsArray[indexPath.row].word
    popupNumberLabel.text = itemsArray[indexPath.row].number
    popupDescriptionLabel.text = itemsArray[indexPath.row].descriptor

    popupCenterConstraint.constant = 0

    print("\(indexPath)")
```

I'm messing around to see what actually works, setting the popupCenterconstraint works on the first click, as does printing the indexPath.  However updating the popup framesize doesn't update unless I click the cell a second time.  This same thing happens with trying to animate the popup frame with cgaffinetransform, etc.

popup is a UIView that starts with the center constraint set out of screen.

Comment: Not clear on the problem.  Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I'll try explaining before adding a screenshot.  According to my code, when I click a collectionviewcell, these things should happen: the popup Uiview size becomes the same size as the size of a collection view cell, the labels on the popup are updated, the popup is appears in the center of the screen, and then the selected index is printed to console.  Here's what actually happens: on first click of a cell, everything happens except for the popup frame size being updated.  Only if I click the same cell a second time, then the frame size is updated.